# Java List of Elements

Tags: java

I am making a game in Java and I am constructing a list of Items using a Hashmap.  The Key is a an abbreviation of the Item, and the value is the item name.  I want to assign an image to each item BUT also be able to call the item wherever I need.

The Image should be optional, while the abbreviation should and Name should be mandatory.

This is an example of my Hash

```
public static HashMap<String, String> head_items = new HashMap<String, String>(){{
        put("DEF"       ,   "Hat");
        put("HH_CH"     ,   "Copper Helm");
        put("HH_BH"     ,   "Bronze Helm");
        put("HH_IH"     ,   "Iron Helm");
        put("HH_SH"     ,   "Steel Helm");
        put("HH_MH"     ,   "Mithril Helm");
    }};
```

Here is what I have tried

```
public static HashMap<HashMap<String, String>, List<String>> mock_list = new HashMap<HashMap<String,String>, List<String>>() {{
    put(("DEF", "HAT"), "/Resources/images/sprites_16x16/player.png")
}};
```

Would I somehow be able to say
(pseudo code)

```
setItem(mock_list.get("DEF")) # this would get "Hat"
setImage(mock_list.somehow_get_the_image_related_to_"DEF")
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank You

Comment: Bronze, steel and Mithril are not elements.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you should have an `Item` class, which has an abbreviation, name, and optional image. Then you can start with a list of items and build a `Map<String, Item>` very easily.

Whenever you find yourself wanting to build more structure into a collection, consider encapsulating related elements. For example, if you have two lists which are always meant to have the same size, with items with the same index being related, you should consider moving to a single list with each element being that pair of related pieces of data. This case is just the same, but in a map form.

Comment: The key word here is "encapsulation".